# A partition in my HDD has no name and can't change ownership

Tags: partitioning, permissions

My first question here.

I partitioned my HDD many years ago while setting up with Ubuntu. Now I see the partitions are strange. One partition (sda 3) of 102GB acts like it's a separate device that has been inserted in the computer. I couldn't copy paste files there before but after changing ownership to my username from root, I can. Another partition (sda 2) has no name and can't use command line to change ownership but I can copy paste files there. These partitions remained unused before, sda 3 because of the permission problem and sda 2 because I didn't even know where it was.
Now I can use them but they seem weirdly located and unorganized. Is there a way to change the name of sda 2? And how can sda 3 be made to look like it's part of the computer, not an external memory?
Here's the screenshot of the partitions from terminal.

Edit: The home folder was somewhere else before, probably at sda 2, I don't exactly remember but I changed it's location.

Edit 2: I actually don't know where sda 2 is located. Sorry if this seems obvious, I'm not familiar with ubuntu file system, I have been a windows user for a long time before.

[image]

Comment: What you see are the names of the mountpoints (this are directories), not the name of partitions. Everything is fine with this, you should leave it as is. Of course, you could use another directory to mount `sda3` but at the end it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @mook765 So it's okay to copy paste files in sda 3? I don't want to leave the space in sda 2 unused but I'm confused where it's located.

Comment: Of course it's ok to paste files there, that's the meaning of partitions, to store data. The mountpoint is just the adress you need to know if you want to find or store data in this partition within your filesystem.